# Python print unicode doesn't show correct symbols

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-unicode

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. When I try something like this in terminal:

```
rfx@digest:/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu$ echo вдлжофыдвж
вдлжофыдвж
```

Symbols are shown correctly. But if try to print unicode symbols using python 2.7 I get this:

```
>>> print u'абв'
ц│ц┌ц≈
```

As python shows I have utf-8 encoding by default for terminal:

```
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'UTF-8'
```

Comment: Does this happen in python 3.2? What about `unicode('абв')`?

Comment: What do you get for `repr(u'абв')` ?

Comment: >>> repr('абв')
"'\\xc1\\xc2\\xd7'"

Comment: That's `repr('абв')`. What is `repr(u'абв')` ?

Comment: Sorry didn't notice. >>> repr(u'абв')
"u'\\xc1\\xc2\\xd7'"

Comment: @LarryBattle Python 2.7. unicode('абв') gives me: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your input is being improperly deciphered by the terminal. This is not a Python problem.

To prove it, use the unicode representation:

```
myunicode = u'\u0430\u0431\u0432'
print myunicode
print myunicode.encode('utf-8')
```

If this does not print the original string `абв` twice, then you need to configure your terminal emulator program correctly.

Comment: Great, I have changed received data character set to UTF-8 in putty config. Now it works.